# Web interface for LDAP management

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

We are going to implement LDAP for centralized authentication in our organization. Which is the best simple LDAP management tool available ?

Comment: Keycloak one of the better way, have advanced web ui, ldap integration, and sql database.

Comment: I asked this here where it should be https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/83497/is-there-an-web-ldap-administration-tool

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found [Gosa](https://oss.gonicus.de/labs/gosa/) to work extremely well. See their site for setup and usage instructions.

Comment: Definitely agree Gosa is an excellent admin tool - but for not ideal for lower-level debugging - phpldapadmin?

Comment: As of 2015 the project seems to be dead.

Comment: For now you could try GOsa fork - Fusiondirectory.

Answer (score 7):

You might take a look at http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.ldap-account-manager.org/
Has the ability to create users homes, handles quotas, creates pdf-s, handles samba3. Batch upload from csv.

Answer (score 5):

I use [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/), and I am very pleased with it.

Comment: I just want to +1 ADS for it's ease of use and full feature set. Some things I like: using an existing entry as a template for another, ease of creating any new entry from scratch, schema viewing, cross platform.

Comment: +1 for ADS for not requiring additional infrastructure that needs maintenance.

Comment: ADS is very good, but my experiences with apache fortress (web frontend before apache directory server) are bad. Apache Directory Studio has the problem that it requires the installation of an eclipse-derivative software to the client machine. I manage LDAP with ADS, but co-workers have a web frontend, too.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not sure what the *best* is - that's a rather subjective question.

I've used [phpLDAPadmin](http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) in the past, and it's worked quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Best free option - phpLDAPadmin.

But if you have some budget - better to buy https://www.ldap-account-manager.org/lamcms/. It has a lot of good things: like self service (users will have possibilities to change password themselves), tree view as phpLDAPadmin has. It cost ~250 euro for now.

As I know phpLDAPadmin and ￼LDAP Account Manager are projects of the same developer. And have the same bugs too :)

**UPD.** Seems that Fusion Directory https://www.fusiondirectory.org/ is also not bad choice especially considering current situation. Its a GOSA fork. Written on PHP, has a lot of integrated schemas, plugins could be added/deleted so interface could be clean w/o non-needed things etc.

https://www.theo-andreou.org/?p=1539
https://fusiondirectory-user-manual.readthedocs.io/en/1.4/